# Error when deploying WAR to WebSphere Portal environment

Tags: java, websphere-portal

I'm trying to deploy an out-of-the-box portlet to my WebSphere Portal 6.0 environment.  I have made minor HTML changes one of the JSPs and any subsequent deployment results in the following errors:

```
EJPAQ1316E: Could not process the selected file from the browse button as a WAR file. Make sure it is a WAR file and try again.

com.ibm.portal.WpsException: EJPAQ1316E: Could not process the selected file from the browse button as a WAR file.  Make sure it is a WAR file and try again.   at com.ibm.wps.portlets.portletmanager.actions.UploadWarFileAction.putDisplayableStringsIntoActionForm(UploadWarFileAction.java:401)    at com.ibm.wps.portlets.portletmanager.actions.UploadWarFileAction.doExecute(UploadWarFileAction.java:244)  at com.ibm.wps.portlets.adminstruts.actions.BaseAction.execute(BaseAction.java:64)  at com.ibm.wps.portlets.struts.WpsRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(WpsRequestProcessor.java:338)   at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274) at com.ibm.wps.portlets.struts.WpsStrutsPortlet.processActionPerformed(WpsStrutsPortlet.java:1947)  at com.ibm.wps.portlets.struts.WpsStrutsPortlet.actionPerformed(WpsStrutsPortlet.java:1637) at com.ibm.wps.portlets.adminstruts.WpsAdminStrutsPortlet.actionPerformed(WpsAdminStrutsPortlet.java:261)   at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.legacy.SPIPortletInterceptorImpl.handleEvents(SPIPortletInterceptorImpl.java:323)

EJPPD0035E: The WAR file D:IBMPortaldeployed empfile.war could not be extracted into directory D:IBMPortaldeployed emp empfile.war.6.

com.ibm.wps.command.applications.AppWarFileException: EJPPD0035E: The WAR file D:IBMPortaldeployed  empfile.war could not be extracted into directory D:IBMPortaldeployed   emp empfile.war.6.WrappedException is: java.io.IOException: The given input stream is not an archive.   at com.ibm.wps.command.applications.AbstractApplicationsCommand.throwAppWarFileException(AbstractApplicationsCommand.java:380)  at com.ibm.wps.command.applications.AbstractApplicationsCommand.extractArchive(AbstractApplicationsCommand.java:714)    at com.ibm.wps.command.applications.GetPortletApplicationInfoCommand.execute(GetPortletApplicationInfoCommand.java:117) at com.ibm.wps.portlets.portletmanager.utils.WebModuleInstallUpdateUtil.getPortletInfoFromWarBytes(WebModuleInstallUpdateUtil.java:297) at com.ibm.wps.portlets.portletmanager.utils.WebModuleInstallUpdateUtil.getConcreteAppsFromFormFile(WebModuleInstallUpdateUtil.java:239)    at com.ibm.wps.portlets.portletmanager.actions.UploadWarFileAction.putDisplayableStringsIntoActionForm(UploadWarFileAction.java:357)    at com.ibm.wps.portlets.portletmanager.actions.UploadWarFileAction.doExecute(UploadWarFileAction.java:244)  at com.ibm.wps.portlets.adminstruts.actions.BaseAction.execute(BaseAction.java:64)

java.io.IOException: The given input stream is not an archive.
java.io.IOException: The given input stream is not an archive.  at com.ibm.wps.util.ArchiveExtracter.extract(ArchiveExtracter.java(Compiled Code))  at com.ibm.wps.util.ArchiveFileUtils.extractArchive(ArchiveFileUtils.java:86)   at com.ibm.wps.command.applications.AbstractApplicationsCommand.extractArchive(AbstractApplicationsCommand.java:712)    at com.ibm.wps.command.applications.GetPortletApplicationInfoCommand.execute(GetPortletApplicationInfoCommand.java:117) at com.ibm.wps.portlets.portletmanager.utils.WebModuleInstallUpdateUtil.getPortletInfoFromWarBytes(WebModuleInstallUpdateUtil.java:297) at com.ibm.wps.portlets.portletmanager.utils.WebModuleInstallUpdateUtil.getConcreteAppsFromFormFile(WebModuleInstallUpdateUtil.java:239)    at com.ibm.wps.portlets.portletmanager.actions.UploadWarFileAction.putDisplayableStringsIntoActionForm(UploadWarFileAction.java:357)    at com.ibm.wps.portlets.portletmanager.actions.UploadWarFileAction.doExecute(UploadWarFileAction.java:244)  at com.ibm.wps.portlets.adminstruts.actions.BaseAction.execute(BaseAction.java:64)
```

Am I doing anything obviously wrong?  As I said, I've made no changes to the actual code, just the way it's laid out.

Thanks

Ronnie

**Update:** Some more information:  I'm trying to re-deploy the portlet *lwp.peoplefinder.jsr168.war*.  The minor changes I mention are really minor, i.e. the removal of 4 `<br>` tags from the file ProfileField_inc.jsp (if anyone's familiar with it).

Comment: Can you unzip the .war?  Is it possible it got corrupted?

Comment: It seems to be fine; I can still unzip it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a known feature of WAS. You **MUST** in case of portlets use the original file names until the doomsday. So if you have ie. build number in the war file name on the first deploy that's what you must use when you redeploy.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the war, deploy as a new, re-drop the portlets to the page or re-run the script.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Did you import the war file as a project into rad? is it free from errors?